# Does any provider have the old Digg links archived or cached?

Tags: cached-webpages, digg

Years ago when Digg was in v2 and v3 I bookmarked (or rather: *hoarded*) hundreds of Digg links. Each Digg page would contain a link to the actual story (years ago).

Is there a way I can find these story links if I have the old Digg links?

Here are two example links:
http://digg.com/news/gaming/Flash_Circle_TowerDefence
http://digg.com/news/entertainment/5_Movies_More_Complicated_Than_Inception

Comment: Could you give an example of an old link?

Comment: I edited my post with two example links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try inputting the Digg URL to the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org).

It looks like they have the Digg homepage archived [going back 10 years](https://web.archive.org/web/*/www.digg.com), so they may have cached copies of your links.

Comment: Yes, I have previously tested the links on the Wayback Machine, but they didn't show up. I just tested it again and about half of my links work. Perhaps it's the relatively new links that weren't archived.

Answer (score 3):

If you were a user at Digg before they have an archive tool, see more information in the following link

http://blog.digg.com/post/30538134581/the-digg-archive

The archive tool is [here](http://digg.com/archive). I don't know if it's working or not but you can try.

Comment: This looked promising but unfortunately only listed a subset of my data, and the data that was listed was incomplete without page URL's. Even so, I'm mainly looking for the story URL's of my bookmarked links, so those won't be in there in any case.